# Can't change the brightness on my new laptop

Tags: 20.04, graphics, brightness

I have bought a new PC and I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. The brightness control on my keyboard works, but the screen brightness does not change.

Here are my computer's specs:

[image: computer specs]

I have tried everything from `/etc/default/grub` to installing `brightness-controller` and also `mainline`. The only solution that I haven't tried is the X11 config file because every post that I have seen uses an Intel processor.

Answer (score 0):

You need a distro with a newer kernel and graphical stack. I'd recommend Ubuntu 22.04.3